# Eclipse: is there a way to get Eclipse to output the commands given to run your program?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I'm having some build issues with Eclipse in that it runs my app just fine in eclipse but for some reason when trying to run using

```
#>java MyClass
```

it ends up not running due to not being able to find the class. This makes no sense so I was wondering if there was a way to have eclipse output what it's feeding into the jvm to get it to build/run.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can get the exact command used by Eclipse like this:

1. Run your program inside Eclipse.
2. Go to the Debug perspective.
3. Terminate the program, or let it end. right click on the second line. (Terminated, exit value... ) and select properties. in there you will have the full command line used.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any way of getting Eclipse to show any command line arguments - but I'm sure we can solve your problem in other ways.

- What is the *full* name of your class? Is it just `MyClass`, or is it in some package? You need to supplied the fully qualified name, e.g.

  ```
  java mypackage.MyClass
  ```
- Where are the class files? You need to make sure they're on the class path, e.g.

  ```
  java -classpath bin mypackage.MyClass
  ```

Comment: Yeah your answer solved my problem. I was not familiar with calling something that was in a package because you seem to have to be 1 directory up in order to call it (ie. you can't be in a the Class directory itself. It'd still be nice if eclipse had that feature though

Comment: It's not a matter of being "one directory up" - it's that the package *root* has to be in the class path, and you have to specify the fully qualified name.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have run a program in eclipse, there is configuration available from the 'debug' and 'run' menus. If you open it, you will see the classpath. From there you can determine what it did.

You can also check the box that writes the launch config to a .launch file, and look at it. It's not precisely the command line, but it will tell you what you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse does not pass anything to your java application unless you tell it to in the launch configuration. Check your classpath and your packages, like Jon Skeet already wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Does not Eclipse show the commands in one of the Consoles?

Answer (score 0):

Note: if you want to see the exact `java` command line Eclipse is launching when running your app (from Eclipse), you can:

- put a breakpoint at the beginning of your class
- launch your app in debug mode
- launch a [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) (if you are on Windows, that is)

[image]
<sub>(source: [maximumpc.com](http://dl.maximumpc.com/galleries/sysinternals/ProcEx01.png))</sub>

You will see under the eclipse.exe (not shown in this picture) the java process.
Double-click on it, go the the `Image` tab, and copy-paste the value of the field "command-line".