# finding what commands are executed by eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have a project in eclipse right now that is compiled using ant. I am wondering what eclipse is doing behind the curtains whenever I double click on the jar target of one of this build files.

Is it possible to get the commands that eclipse is executing with ant, as I'd like to setup a shell script that compiles the project. How can I find what commands it is actually executing and what parameters it is passing.

I imagine there are also some variables like classpath, and buildpath that are set, where do I find them as to be easily copied over.

Eclipse comes with its own installation of ant. Is it possible to use that bundled installation of ant to build via command line.

Any help appreciated,

Ted.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this on Linux by any change?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to look at the process executed by Eclipse when building.
For that, use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) (if you are on Windows) in order to display the full command line and all its parameter when running that build.

Comment: Similar idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989419/eclipse-is-there-a-way-to-get-eclipse-to-output-the-commands-given-to-run-your/1989645#1989645